# Pretty boxes not rendering correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, display

Today I notice that the box around the box around the user information is not rendering correctly in my browser. I'm using Chrome 47 on Windows 7. Here is a screenshot:

[image: incompletely rendered boxes with lovely hand-drawn green circles.]

Yes, I drew those circles by hand. w00t.

Also, I did refresh my cache, then reboot my machine, then I took off and nuked the entire site from orbit because it was the only way to be sure.

You'll note that I also circled the question box, but that seems to have always been that way and I was too dense to notice.

Comment: Me too. For all other questions. What did you do to us?

Comment: I also see this. I'm using Firefox 42.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm on chrome 46.0.2490.86, Mac OS 10.10

Comment: This error is in the `all.css` style sheet; it is browser and OS independent.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with my iPad SE app this morning...

Comment: The box around the user information seems to be fixed for me now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been corrected. Sorry for inconvenience.

[image]

Comment: Looks legit. Thanks!

Comment: The User-info box looks good, but from where I'm sitting, the question-title box still overlaps the site header....

Comment: @Hellion I'm not sure what the exact issue with the question-title box is. [Per this post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/updates-to-the-site) it appears that navigation moved into the header and there was never a top portion to the title box.

Comment: @Hynes, I see from the screenshots that you're right, but now I have to wonder if it would look better if the box around the title were a complete box.  I would probably never have noticed it on my own, but now that it's been pointed out to me, I don't like how it looks.

Comment: @Hellion Sounds like a [feature-request] to me. :)